# where to put events on Android swipe view page?

Tags: android, swipe

using this tutorial: http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/swipe-views/?lang=en, I now can create a swiping pages based on several xml files.

Let's say the first page is tab1.xml, and it contains:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="this is my button"
    android:onClick="myButton_onClick" />
```

and the second page of is tab2.xml and it has:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/something" />
```

now my app can swipe from one page to another, which is exactly what I want it to be. However, when I try to control the `<Button>` and `<ImageView>`, on MainActivity.java, it always gives me nullpointerexception error.

I then realize that both `<Button>` and `<ImageView>` is not a part of activity_main.xml, so then it might not be accessible from MainActivity.java. In fact activity_main.xml only contains a title of each swipeable pages. Now I don't even know where to put the onClick event for my Button.

I wish some android experts could point me a clue.

Log:

```
11-05-21:48:50.061: D/ActivityThread(13482): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
11-05-21:48:50.061: D/ActivityThread(13482): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
11-05-21:48:50.061: D/ActivityThread(13482): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
11-05-21:48:50.251: W/dalvikvm(13482): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c5e498)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at com.anggrian.speaknow.MainActivity$TabFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:152)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15247)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4834)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15247)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15247)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4834)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15247)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1881)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1129)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1027)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4359)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4812)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
11-05-21:48:50.251: E/AndroidRuntime(13482):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access those views from the Fragments that contain them. Get a reference to those elements in the Fragment's `onCreateView` method, and handle any action in there as well, or in the `onActivityCreated` if you want to be on the safe side.

In the example you provide, you'd do this :

```
public static class TabFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);
     ImageView img = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img);
     img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_drawable);
     // Get a reference to your button and add onClick listener here as well
     return rootView;
}

}
```

Comment: maybe make sure that the layout you are inflating contains the element you're trying to access. If you're inflating tab1.xml, the ImageView will not be there because it's part of tab2.xml, and vice versa.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you set onClick in the xml, which will look for a similarly named method in the Activity. I would recommend declaring the method in the Fragment itself and calling it from the onClick programatically, by doing button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener...);

Comment: If you could post some code and the LogCat, it would definitely help ;)

Comment: ah sorry I didn't know it could be helpful at all, I just posted it

Comment: Most ViewPager examples out there are pretty bad, starting with the one you provided ;) Because of the way it is written, it gives you little control over the UI elements in your Fragments, this one only works because they all contain static textviews that are never accessed in code. Try this example, bearing in mind you'll have to amend its design to remove any arguments from the Fragments constructors, and use the fragment.setArguments(args) method instead to pass data to your Fragments : http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/

Comment: I can see where this is going now, thanks for that helpful link!